# In python, how to send base64 str via webdis?

Tags: webdis

in broswer, I subcribe a channel:

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:7379/.json");
socket.onopen = function() {
    socket.send(JSON.stringify(["SUBSCRIBE", "mychannel"]));
};
socket.onmessage = function(evt)
{
    console.log(evt.data);
};
```

in python,I can publish a message, and broswer receive it, code is:

```
import request
requests.put('http://127.0.0.1:7379/publish/mychannel/{}'.format('1'*80240))
```

but I can't send message in base64, because base64 data have '/' in it; Is there a way send msg use body(json)? The code may be like follow:

```
import request
requests.put('http://127.0.0.1:7379/publish/mychannel', json={'value':"base64str"})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send values to Webdis that do not fit nicely in a URL by sending them as the request body using a `PUT` request. This is documented in the Webdis README under the section titled "[File Upload](https://github.com/nicolasff/webdis/#file-upload)".

Let's say you wanted to store the value `hello/world` under the key `greeting`. As you wrote, you can't just send `/SET/greeting/hello/world`, but you can send all the parameters *except the last one* in the URL, and then the last one as the `PUT` body. This means the `PUT` body is the exact value to set, it is **not** a JSON message containing the value.

To do this in Python with Requests:

```py
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.put('http://127.0.0.1:7379/SET/greeting', data=b'hello/world', headers={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'})
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.text
'{"SET":[true,"OK"]}'
```

And we can verify that the value was sent correctly:

```
>>> r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:7379/GET/greeting')
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.text
'{"GET":"hello/world"}'
```

This should work just the same way for your `PUBLISH` example. I ran your JavaScript code in a browser and then used Requests to send the same value to `http://127.0.0.1:7379/PUBLISH/mychannel`, and the following was logged in the browser console:

```
{"SUBSCRIBE":["message","mychannel","hello/world"]}
```

You almost have it right with the `PUT` request code in your last block, except that in this case you don't have to send JSON but can send the raw value directly in the `data` parameter – even the contents a binary file, which is why this is documented as "file upload". In some cases you might still want to use base 64 encoding, especially if the subscriber can't handle the raw data.

As a side note, there is yet another way to do this with Webdis: you can also fully URL-encode the value and not send `hello/world` but `hello%2Fworld`, for example with `encodeURIComponent` in JavaScript or `urllib.parse.quote(value, safe='')` in Python. Sending `/SET/greeting/hello%2Fworld` in a `GET` request will work. This is documented under "[Command format](https://github.com/nicolasff/webdis#command-format)" in the README.

This isn't the first time this question has been asked, there was [a recent question](https://github.com/nicolasff/webdis/issues/206) on GitHub that was similar. I've been working on [adding more documentation to Webdis](https://github.com/nicolasff/webdis/tree/master/docs) and will try to highlight this case since it seems common.

Comment: I have test it, it work well, thank you for you contribution.

Answer (score 0):

direct use redis's publish in python, so I should expose 6379, modify the redis.conf, and build the docker.

dickerfile:

```
FROM nicolas/webdis:0.1.19
MAINTAINER author "https://github.com/m986883511"
WORKDIR /m986883511
USER root

EXPOSE 6379
EXPOSE 7379

RUN sed -i '2i"websockets":   true,' /etc/webdis.prod.json
RUN sed -i "s/127.0.0.1/0.0.0.0/g" /etc/redis.conf
```

python code:

```
import redis
from backend.business import transfer

r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)

path = 'test.png'
value = transfer.bytes_to_base64(path, True)
r.publish('mychannel', value)
```